# Prevent ng-click action on hitting enter

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have written a `timepicker` directive, where I can enter the time and if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the value will be formatted in a specific time format. Also the input will be blur. That all works fine.

The problem is that I also have some buttons in the form with the `ng-click` directive. And if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the action of the `ng-click` directive will also be called. Although I run `e.preventDefault();`

This is the code of my directive:

```
$element.keyup(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.witch;

  if (keyCode == 13) {
    $element.blur();

    // Do some more stuff here
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

And the HTML code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openModal()">
  <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
</button>
```

The funny thing is that the `timepicker` directive works as expected and additional the `openModal()` function will be called. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your button needs a `type="button"`. By default it is `type="submit"` which is why it is being called as the form submits.

It also looks like you need to prevent form submission when you press enter, but that's a different problem.

Comment: funny my "<button ..." without specifying type doesn't respond to my hitting enter though I wanted it to!!

Comment: Nice one! Solved my problem ;).